# How to hide PHPMyAdmin on a Google Cloud VM

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-platform, hosting

I'm trying to remove public access to PHPMyAdmin on my Google Cloud VM. Has anyone done this so that you can access it privately?

It would be awesome if you could only see the /phpmyadmin path when you were authenticated as a user on the WordPress installation there but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

While thinking how to reply to you I've found an already answered question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938398/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin) that is written well

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I don't use PHPMyAdmin

But there are some general options to filter out certain paths:
1. If you server is accessible via GCP LB, define a host rule to redirect /phpmyadmin to other routes 
2. PHPMyAdmin should have some whitelisting function, you can Google it
3. Put a proxy server e.g. Nginx in front of PHP and do routing